# PHP append text in new line for new entry

Tags: php

I am trying to write text in new line when ever the entry is written am not able to do tat as of now am using time date when a new entry is made it is coming next to old entry.

`05-01-2016, 16:33 - 2016-01-05 04:01:1905-01-2016, 16:33 - 2016-01-05 04:01:20
-01-05 04:01:14a2016-01-05 04:01:15a2016-01-05 04:01:15a2016-01-05 04:01:16`

```
$timezone = "Asia/Colombo";
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $today = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
    echo $today;

    $myfile = fopen("D:\Log\log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "user id date";
fwrite($myfile, "a". $today ."\n");
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` for new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fwrite with PHP_EOL

```
fwrite($myfile, "a". $today .PHP_EOL);
```

If that will not works You can try

```
fwrite($myfile, "a". $today ."\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file      = "/your_file_path/your_file_name.txt";
file_put_contents($file, print_r($your_content, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

first set your path of file and append your new content with `FILE_APPEND` in `file_put_contents`  and give permission to your folder where files stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this code, it works well :

```
fwrite($myfile, "\r\n"."a".$today);
```